# response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: laravel, email

I'm trying to send reset password link to users,So I login in mailtrap.io with cpanel email and get username and password.
My .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=0b2cd732d22391
MAIL_PASSWORD=""
```

But when I send user email I give this Error:
`response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted`.
Where is my wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
MAIL_PASSWORD=""
```

If your password is empty string(i think this impossible), you need to change to this

```
MAIL_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: @HanieAsemi it`s free mailtrap account? in my opinion they give password